# MySQL Adapter with C# Entity Framework - connection slow after idle

Tags: .net, mysql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a program in .NET 4 with Entity Framework and MySQL with MySQL.NET adapter version 6.5.4.  After I leave the program idle for some time (like 5 minutes) and try to do a search of the database, there will be a lag of about 5-6 seconds.  But after that, the search will be quick again.

I did a profiling of the lag and found that the entity framework is trying to re-establish a connection to the database after certain idle time and thus causing the lag.  Since my program will be used only in a small group around 20 machines, I would like to keep the connection always active to speed up the lookup.  Is there a way to do that?  If not, how can I improve the connection speed to MySQL in this case?

**Edit (Update):**

I found out after I set "Min Pool Size=1" in the connection string, there won't be any lag even after idle for a long time.  It seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Persistent connections are very rarely a good idea, but with that said...

You could execute this command on the ObjectContext:

```
yourObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET SESSION wait_timeout=28800;");
```

This should tell the database to keep your connection open for 8 hours.

Comment: Thanks EkoostikMartin.  I didn't try your solution yet.  But found out that if I set "Min Pool Size=1" in the connection string then the problem goes away.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's a non-standard connection string argument, I guess it's specific to the driver you are using. If you ever change MySQL drivers though this won't work anymore.

Comment: Connection string options for MySQL .NET provider: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html